# Which governments have carried out programmes of forcible vaccination and when?

Tags: government, public-health, brazil, vaccine

In 1904, some 16 years after the law abolishing slavery, the government of Brazil ordered "sanitary brigades" accompanied by police units to enter homes in Rio de Janeiro and vaccinate residents against smallpox by force. This action triggered the [Vaccine Revolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaccine_Revolt), including in the predominantly Afro-Brazilian district of Saude. After 30 people were killed the authorities abandoned forcible vaccination, only to reintroduce it in 1909 after [removing many working class people from central Rio](https://library.brown.edu/create/fivecenturiesofchange/chapters/chapter-5/modernization-in-rio/) and deporting hundreds of rebels by packet boat.

**On what other occasions either in Brazil or in the rest of the world have governments carried out programmes of forcible vaccination?**

Comment: @Federico - Yes, but not the requirement of vaccination as a condition of school admission when school admission itself is not compulsory.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on vaccination policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaccination_policy) has a table which shows various countries currently having mandatory vaccinations against various diseases.

Comment: @Philipp - Thanks! I had no idea there were so many instances. One can sort the table by "strictest policy" too. I will write an answer to my own question based on that page. But I'd be interested if someone has the details to hand regarding dates.

Comment: @Federico - Which such countries are you are aware of?

Comment: are listed in the wikipedia table and you already included them in the answer.

Comment: The article doesn't mention vaccination at birth. Indeed are any vaccinations given at birth? DTP is often given at two months. (The WP article on DTP is wrong to state that the British state health service the NHS gives it "to all teenagers aged 14". A "booster" is offered at that age, but it is neither compulsory nor universally accepted.)

Comment: yes, I used "at birth" in an extremely improper way.

Comment: How much force counts as forcible? In Canada, you can't attend public school if you have not been jabbed.

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/65630/why-is-there-so-much-reluctance-to-make-the-covid-vaccine-mandatory-for-adults

Answer (score 3):

(Many thanks to @Philipp for the reference.)

According to [Wikipedia's entry on vaccination policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaccination_policy), the following 15 countries have a policy of forcible vaccination:

***13 in Europe***

consisting of

- 9 which used to belong to, or were parts of countries that belonged to, either the Warsaw Treaty Organisation or Yugoslavia:

**Bulgaria

Croatia

Czechia

Hungary

Poland

Serbia

Slovakia

Slovenia

Ukraine**

- and 4 others:

**France

Germany

Italy

Malta**

***2 elsewhere in the world***

**Brazil

Indonesia**

Comment: Germany has no forced vaccionations (and Wikipedia does not say it has). However as of March this year unvaccinated children might not be allowed to attend kindergarten and schools (and since school attendance is mandatory one might argue that this is forced vaccination through a backdoor).

Comment: @EikePierstorff the table shows a mandatory MMR vaccine for Germany

Comment: Ah I see. This should be probably  be rather in the "nurseries, preschools and kindergartens" category. So yes, it is forced, but not on all of the population (which is how I understood the question), but only on people who are "betreut in Gemeinschaftseinrichtungen", i.e. cared for in community facilities.

Comment: However up until 1974 vaccination against smallpox was mandatory in Germany (was discontinued because infections had fallen to a point where the risk did not justify the potentially nasty side effect of the vaccines used back then).

Comment: I think you are confusing "forced" (a term not used normally) with "mandatory" (i.e. a legal requirement).  People are not *forced* as such - e.g. armed police do not generally grab you and your children kicking and screaming and force an injection on you.

Comment: My German children, born in 1989 and 1991, were inoculated against TB, diphtheria and smallpox immediately after birth. There was no way to contest this (and I would not have wanted to anyway). I gather they don't bother with smallpox any more.

Comment: Interestingly none are enforcing it for adults, though I guess it would only be relevant for immigrants and new diseases like COVID.